# How to use a template in listview (asp.net, c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have many pages that are showing same results in same layout (like search results, top viewed, recent added etc) If i want to change any field, i have to do this in all of the pages. Is it possible to have a template or usercontrol in listview where i can change this in one place and how to pass the id parameter?

Additional information:
Now i have something like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="id">
    <ItemTemplate>
                 Id:
         <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
         Description:
         <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
              Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

What i woild like to have is:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="id">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <usrCtrl:info ID="info1" runat="server" /> 
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and a file with template:

```
Id:
<asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
Description:
<asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
```

Thanks, Jim Oak

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**ListView:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="ListView2_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <usrCtrl:info Description_Lbl='<%# Bind("id") %>' 
                 ID_Lbl='<%# Bind("Description") %>' ID="info1"  runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**User Control Code:**

**info.ascx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
                    CodeBehind="info.ascx.cs" Inherits="info" %>
<asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server"  />
Description:
<asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server"  />
```

**info.ascx.cs:**

```
public partial class info: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string ID_Lbl {get;set;}
    public string Description_Lbl { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDLabel.Text = ID_Lbl;
        DescriptionLabel.Text = Description_Lbl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This looks like a solution for me, the only thing is i cannot get the results. There is  "Description:" but the data fields are empty.

Comment: the value didn't come up for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You can create a User Control (*.ascx file) with the entire ListView, and then expose DataSource to bind the data from your page.

I found this post helpful:

[How to set DataSource property in.aspx file of a user control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659611/how-to-set-datasource-property-in-aspx-file-of-a-user-control)